# How to set pivot when the model zoom-in

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

It is found on BIM360 viewer has set pivot when zooming feature, but this feature not available in native viewer. I'm try to used `viewer.navigation.setPivotPoint(point);`, but I don't know how to get zooming after mouse position.

[BIM360 Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WRLA.gif)

Answer (score 0):

Just call `vieewr.navigation.setWheelSetsPivot(true)` to active this behavior.

If you want to make it your viewer app's default behavior, you can change it in the viewer profile settings.

```js
let viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(document.getElementById('forgeViewer'), config3d);
let startedCode = viewer.start();
if (startedCode > 0) {
  console.error('Failed to create a Viewer: WebGL not supported.');
  return;
}

const profileSettings = Autodesk.Viewing.ProfileSettings.clone(Autodesk.Viewing.ProfileSettings.AEC);
profileSettings.settings.wheelSetsPivot = true;

const profile = new Autodesk.Viewing.Profile(profileSettings);
viewer.setProfile(profile);

//Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(documentId, onDocumentLoadSuccess, onDocumentLoadFailure);
```